# My core_session DB table is getting to heavy very quick

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Few months back my website sessions use to get recorded in var/session folder. Suddenly one day I was not able to delete that folder. I also tried using commands but It didnt work. Because of this my indoes level went high and website ended up crashion. So I have shifted my session files to DB, where I can easily truncate if required. But since few days my Website suddenly gets super slow, maybe because I am also upgrading my website to Magento 2.0 and its in the same server. But when I check my DB tables the core_session file size is increasing my 400 mb each day. I dont know where I am going wrong or the cron job settings are wrong. Please if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Don't use db for the session. Try to use Redis.

Comment: Till you migrate to Magento 2 I would return the session to files. rm the session folder not its contents. And set up a cron to remove files via shell_exec and mtime for older than a week files. If you want more information leave me a comment.